# at least one column length of the schema from the input link is different with the schema defined in the component

Tags: talend

I'm getting a warning

> at least one column length of the schema from the input link is different with the schema defined in the component.

[sic] on a tPostgresqlOutput but can't see the cause of the error by eyeballing.

How can I determine exactly which column is causing the warning?

Comment: there is an option of doing sync of schema..if you can do that it should sync input and output schema.

Comment: Is there a way to then get the corrected type back to the repository?

Answer (score 1):

If you have identified which column is correct you can update the schema from job directly.
[image]

If you have too manu columns, you can export as XML wanted schema
[image]

And import it in your generic schema
[image]

I hope it helps :)